# Are the opinions of a United States superior court public knowledge?

Tags: united-states, court-records

If I bring a case to a superior court and I lose, is that information public knowledge?

What are the ramifications to me?  For example, could it hurt my credit score?

Answer (score 7):

If you are worried that some secret will become public, you should find and meet with an *attorney*, not a financial adviser or other nonlawyer. *Your* attorney is able to shield your secret information from disclosure in ways other professionals cannot. Raise any credit score issues you're concerned about.

In general, the public has a right to access judicial records. *See* [*Nixon v. Warner Communications, Inc.*, 435 US 589, 597 (1978)](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_case?case=355909589853635487&hl=en&as_sdt=6&as_vis=1&oi=scholarr#p597) (noting that the right is rarely litigated and not clearly defined). That right is not absolute; some records can be sealed, which means that the public can't read them. Local rules govern when that happens. I don't think the *existence* of a civil lawsuit could be made secretly except in special circumstances. Likewise, the plaintiff usually must identify herself, except in special circumstances.

A plaintiff should assume that everything about the lawsuit--who filed it, against whom, what evidence arises, the trial, and who wins and loses--will be public.